# Error when trying to open my localhost

Tags: wampserver

Hello guys
i have installed wamp server Version 2.0 .. and i have tried some things and every thing ok ..
i have reboot my Desktop then some thing goes wrong when i am trying to open my local host

EMDAEMON

HTTP/1.1 404 , Not Found

should i consider re-installation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved .... it seems that we have conflicts in ports ..change port in apache make it works

Answer (score 0):

Reboot desktop? Open your local host? If you want to do web development you should get familiar with basic computer terminology, at least to a point when you are able to make questions that make a minimum sense.

I'll assume you have installed a bundle that includes the Apache web server and you want to configure a virtual host that's served when you load `http://emdaemon` in your web browser. The exact details to do so vary slightly depending on your platform. Being a newbie, I suggest you reuse the main site that's already configured and can be loaded through `http://localhost`. It's roughly explained at http://www.wampserver.com/en/presentation.php. Leave multiples sites for the future :)

Comment: thanks for your valuable information Alvaro :) really i dont know what to do with out them... did u get my problem ... i guess no

Comment: Well, if the link does nothing to solve it, then I gess I'm not getting your problem :(